# How to circle div into alignment the left,right,up,down button in html,css?

Tags: html, css

I create the `circle div`. This div into alignment the 4 direction button. How to do this? I did not set correctly. if use margin-top, left, right, bottom not correctly alignment. Below my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/wncv4h0s/1/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class ='circleBase' id='rotateMode'>

<button id="left" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>

 <button id="right" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>

 <button id="up" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>

<button id="down" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>

</div>

#rotateMode{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: gray;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;

}

#left{

}

#right{


}

#up{

}

#down{

}
```

Comment: like this : https://jsfiddle.net/wncv4h0s/5/ ?

Comment: Thank you so much@TemaniAfif

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
    #rotateMode{
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 125px;
      height: 125px;
      background-color: gray;
      color:white;
      position:absolute;
    }
    #left,
    #right,
    #up,
    #down { position:absolute; width:20px; height:20px; cursor:pointer;}

    #left,
    #right {
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
        transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
    #up,
    #down {
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
        transform:translateX(-50%);
    }

    #left {
        left:0;
    }

    #right{
        right:0;
    }

    #up{
        top:0;
    }
    #down{
        bottom:0;
    }
</style>
<div class ="circleBase" id="rotateMode">   
    <button id="left" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>
    <button id="right" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
    <button id="up" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
    <button id="down" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `absolute` position in arrow buttons. Position them directly like for `left` button use `left:0px` and `top:50%`. 
Now use `transform:translateY(-50%)` to vertically align button center with circle center.

```css
#rotateMode{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: gray;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
 
}

#left{
 position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0px;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

#right{
 position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:0px;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

#up{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

#down{
 position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

<div class ='circleBase' id='rotateMode'>

<button id="left" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>

 <button id="right" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
 
 <button id="up" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
 
<button id="down" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make one wrapper around the up bottom `.top` , one wrapper around the left/right button `.middle` and one wrapper around the down bottom `.bottom`. After this use `flexbox` on the `#rotateMode` to place them in a column. After that you can just use again flexbox and `justify-content` within the wrappers top/middle/bottom to place up/down bottom centered and left/right with space-between on the sides. Here's a guide, how flexbox works: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here's also my codepen: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/VXEBNb

```css
#rotateMode {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  /* USE FLEXBOX */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  justify-content: center;
}

.middle {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='circleBase' id='rotateMode'>
  <div class="top">
    <button id="up" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
  </div>

  <div class="middle">
    <button id="left" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>
    <button id="right" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <button id="down" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```